# how to give UIImage negative color effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

This is my first question.
I have an app in which i want to change the image effect look like negative color effect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's so simple you have to choose image and set the image in the below code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(renderImage.size);
 CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeCopy);
 [renderImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, renderImage.size.width, renderImage.size.height)];
 CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeDifference);
 CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
 CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, renderImage.size.width, renderImage.size.height));
 renderImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 4):

Make a method:

```
 - (UIImage *)makeImageNegative:(UIImage *)image{
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
 CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeCopy);
 [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
 CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeDifference);
 CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),[UIColor       whiteColor].CGColor);
 CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0,   image.size.width, image.size.height));
 UIImage *returnImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
 return returnImage;
 }
```

Comment: @Jennis agree with your comment

Comment: yeah sorry i wrote it while you were writing it

Comment: When merging 2 png images with transparency I get their negative colours on a white background though. Trying to solve that out for some time now. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just discovered any image on a png image with transparency appears blue-ish... Any suggestions would be more than welcome! Thanks :)